# Instead of insert, alter column before insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Trying to create a trigger that will get a data, then replace it to the column that is supposed to be inserted.

```
ALTER trigger beflogs 
ON dbo.tbl_logs
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @tc INT

        SELECT @tc = COUNT(*) 
        FROM dbo.tbl_logs;VALUES(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)

        UPDATE dbo.tbl_logs
        SET id = @tc+1
        FROM dbo.tbl_logs
        INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.id = dbo.tbl_logs.id
    END
```

What seems to be the missing part, the trigger successfully completed, but whenever I try to insert data, there is no result.

Comment: `INSTEAD OF INSERT` means do not insert. Change it to `BEFORE/AFTER INSERT`

Comment: @cha while correct, there are no `before` triggers in sql server. it is possible to insert into the table inside the `instead of insert` trigger.

Comment: but how can i insert my data on that trigger, currently whenever i run an insert statement nothing is added to my rows

Comment: Nothing is inserted into the table because you have an `instead of insert` trigger.

Comment: Explain what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the sample demo here,

```
   CREATE TABLE dbo.data (
    id INT
    ,NAME VARCHAR(10)
    ,StoreId INT
    )

CREATE TRIGGER beflogs ON dbo.data
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN
    DECLARE @tc INT

    SELECT @tc = COUNT(*)
    FROM dbo.data;

    INSERT dbo.data (
        ID
        ,NAME
        ,StoreId
        )
    SELECT id = @tc + 1
        ,I.NAME
        ,I.StoreId
    FROM inserted I
END

INSERT INTO DATA (NAME,StoreId) VALUES ('A',10)
INSERT INTO DATA (NAME,StoreId) VALUES ('B',20)

SELECT *FROM DATA
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it will do what is probably hoped for in the event of a multirow insert, or in the event of concurrent inserts.